# How to integrate phpBB with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, module, integration, phpbb3

Is there any way to integrate phpBB with Wordpress. I already have a wordpress blog and I need to integrate phpBB to it. I want to synchronize the user table of both phpBB and wordpress. User can access both sites by logging into anyone of the sites. Can anyone help me on this...

Comment: You can't integrate the user tables. However, you might be able to write some code to share the authentication. Look for session sharing tutorials on the phpBB boards.

Comment: @JohnP thanks! a link will be helpful...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **can** integrate/synchronize the user tables. There's even a plugin for that, see  [WP phpBB Bridge](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-phpbb-bridge/).

As an aside: I agree that as a standalone forum, phpBB is by far the best opensource/free solution. For WP, there's also the excellent [simple:press](http://simple-press.com/) forum. Using that instead of phpBB is definitely more future-proof, less maintenance requiring once setup and easier to optically integrate into the site. It might look pretty ugly at first, but its css is very flexible and with a bit of tinkering, you can integrate it very well.

**EDIT**

It having just received an upvote, I revisited this answer. And it being 2 years old, I want to add that given recent decisions of the dev team, I feel less inclined to recommend simple:press over going the extra mile and integrating phpBB...

Comment: Thanks for helping me.. I have already started working on phpBB so I cannot go with 'Simple Press' forum. I have also tried WP phpBB Bridge. The issue I faced was that I cannot access the admin dashboard as it was redirecting to the phpBB forum page. How can I change the behaviour in the case of wordpress admin user..

Comment: You can migrate content from phpBB to bbPress, which is also forum plugin for WordPress, using CMS2CMS tool. This moves posts, topics, users, attachments, categories etc.

Comment: Genuine altruistic help or self-endorsement there, @Christina?

Comment: Why not combine both, Johannes? I disclosed my occupation in the profile.

Answer (score 2):

I think BBPress Forum is best idea to integrate with wordpress. I recently integrate the BBPress Forum with one my wordpress blog. You can get guide for adding BBPress Forum from here http://www.bloggingalerts.com/2011/11/how-to-integrate-forum-with-wordpress.html

Answer (score 2):

[WP-United](http://www.wp-united.com) provides modules for both single sign-on and template integration. It does both of these automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, follow these steps exactly, this took me days to work out.

1. Install wordpress and phpbb as normal.
2. Make sure you are logged out of wordpress (otherwise you will get a gap at the top of your phpbb header, where the wordpress admin bar would go).
3. Now go to your wordpress blog page, (when you are logged out of wordpress admin) and right click, go to view source.
4. Copy the source from the top of the page until you see a div like page content etc (will vary on your theme), remember we just want the header.
5. Now paste that right at the top of your your overall_header.php in your phpbb template.
6. Now go to your phpbb admin, and go to styles, then templates, click refresh on your current template, so that the overall_header.php will be re-cached with the changes we have made.
7. You can do the footer in the same way, copy the footer html from the wordpress page that you want to use, and add it to overall_footer.php.
8. You can ever get the same styles by linking your css file from your blog to phpbb.

You should now be able to link to your phpbb and it will have a wordpress header.

Answer (score 0):

i have used [wp-phpbb-bridge](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-phpbb-bridge/) with these steps:

1) after installation of the plugin, activate it;

2) set the correct paths of phpbb directory in the plugin's settings.

3) go to Widgets and put the Phpbb Bridge Users (or which one) you need into the sidebar.

then the users(login or other data) will be automatically synchronized.

this method worked for me.